# What are French equivalents to the Latin “id est”?

Tags: locutions, latin

I know that “*that is*” comes from Latin “*id est*”, short “*i.e.*” and means “in other words”.

I would like to know whether there is a French equivalent for this phrase.

Comment: [C’est-à-dire](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/id%20est)

Comment: Note that `i.e.` is also used in french as is, especially (but not limited) to refering scientific work (mathematical, for instance).

Comment: @mansuetus, Good point!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the closest translation of “that is” would be “***c’est-à-dire***”, which litterally means “that is to say”. It can be shortened to “*c-à-d*” or “*c.a.d.*”

“***Autrement dit***” and “***en d’autres termes***” also both exactly mean “in other words”.

Comment: It’s exactly what I’m looking for, the more variants the better. Much obliged!

Comment: @LucianSava Note the the shortened version is not nearly as common as “i.e.” is in English, I think you should generally avoid it in formal writing.

Comment: @Annoyed, duly noted!

Answer (score 3):

à savoir is the French equivalent of Latin's 'id est'

Comment: In some contexts *à savoir* might be a good equivalent. But would you care to elaborate a little more?

Comment: "the" French equivalent? No.

Comment: I think one can une _à savoir_ and _c'est-à-dire_ quite interchangeably, although the latter is more common.